# Reducing Size Of SQL Backup?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Express 2005 and do a backup of all DB's every night. I noticed one DB getting larger and larger. I looked at the DB and cannot see why its getting so big! I was wondering if its something to do with the log file?

Looking for tips on how to find out why its getting so big when its not got that much data in it - Also how to optimise / reduce the size?

Comment: Can you clarify please if it is your database backup files that are growing in size or if the overall database files sizes are increasing. The results of sp_helpdb 'DatabaseName' would be useful too if you are able to make them available.

Comment: When you say the DB is getting bigger, how are you measuring this??  Is it the mdf file size, ldf file size, backup file size, or some other method??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Several things to check:

- is your database in "Simple" recovery mode? If so, it'll produce a lot less transaction log entries, and the backup will be smaller. Recommended for development - but not for production
- if it's in "FULL" recovery mode - do you do regular transaction log backups? That should limit the growth of the transaction log and thus reduce the overall backup size
- have you run a `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(yourdatabasename)` on it lately? That may help
- do you have any log / logging tables in your database that are just filling up over time? Can you remove some of those entries?

You can find the database's recovery model by going to the Object Explorer, right click on your database, select "Properties", and then select the "Options" tab on the dialog:

[image]

Marc

Comment: For clarity if I may, one point to keep in mind is that the size of the Transaction Log does not really have that much of an impact on the overall size of a Full Database backup file. Keep in mind that a FULL database backup contains the data pages (from the .mdf file) and only incorporates the small portion of the Transaction Log File that’s exists between the start and end of the FULL database backup creation. This is because this portion of the log contains the only data that has changed since the backup of the physical data pages.

Answer (score 14):

If it is the backup that keeps growing and growing, I had the same problem. It is not a 'problem' of course, this is happening by design - you are just making a backup 'set' that will simply expand until all available space is taken.

To avoid this, you've got to change the overwrite options. In the SQL management studio, right-click your DB, TASKS - BACKUP, then in the window for the backup you'll see it defaults to the 'General' page. Change this to 'Options' and you'll get a different set of choices.

The default option at the top is 'Append to the existing media set'. This is what makes your backup increase in size indefinitely. Change this to 'Overwrite all existing backup sets' and the backup will always be only as big as one entire backup, the latest one.

(If you have a SQL script doing this, turn 'NOINIT' to 'INIT')

CAUTION: This means the backup will only be the latest changes - if you made a mistake three days ago but you only have last night's backup, you're stuffed. Only use this method if you have a backup regime that copies your .bak file daily to another location, so you can go back to any one of those files from previous days.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are running with the FULL recovery model and the Transaction Log is growing continuously as the result of no Transaction Log backups being taken.

In order to rectify this you need to:

- Take a transaction log backup. (See: [BACKUP(TRANSACT-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) )
- Shrink the transaction log file down
  to an appropriate size for your needs. (See:[How to use DBCC SHRINKFILE.......](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907511))
- Schedule regular transaction log
  backups according to data recovery
  requirements.

I suggest reading the following Microsoft reference in order to ensure that you are managing your database environment appropriately.

[Recovery Models and Transaction Log Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366344.aspx)

Further Reading: [How to stop the transaction log of a SQL Server database from growing unexpectedly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873235)

Answer (score 0):

One tip for keeping databases small would be at design time, use the smallest data type that you can use.

for Example you may have a status table, do you really need the index to be an int, when a smallint or tinyint will do?

**Darknight**

Comment: Good point for new development - in this case, it might require actually changing existing database schema, which is a bit drastic just to get backup size down...

Comment: I'd say that it'd be a rare database where this helps much, and you are just trading a little space for a bunch of database errors when you reach the limit. Also it doesn't answer why the OPs DB is growing.

Answer (score 0):

as you do a daily FULL backup for your Database , ofcourse it will get so big with time . 
so you have to put a plan for your self . as this 
1st day: FULL
/ 2nd day: DIFFERENTIAL
/ 3rd day: DIFFERENTIAL
/ 4th day: DIFFERENTIAL
/ 5th day: DIFFERENTIAL

and then start over .

and when you restore your database , if you want to restore the FULL you can do it easily , but when you need to restore the DIFF version , you backup the first FULL before it with " NO-recovery " then the DIFF you need , and then you will have your data back safely .

Answer (score 0):

7zip your backup file for archiving. I recently backed up a database to a 178MB .bak file. After archiving it to a .7z file is was only 16MB.
http://www.7-zip.org/

If you need an archive tool that works with larger files sizes more efficiently and faster than 7zip does, I'd recommend taking a look at LZ4 archiving. I have used it for archiving file backups for years with no issues:
http://lz4.github.io/lz4/