# How to control growing SQL database day by day

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, backup

I have an SQL database which has a main Orders table taking 2-5 new rows per day. 
Other table which has daily records is Log table. It receives new data every time a user accesses the login page of the web site including time and the IP address of the user. It gets 10-15 new rows per day for now.

As I monitor the daily backup of SQL, I realized that it is growing like 2-3MB per day. I have enough storage but it makes me worried. Is it the Log table causing this growth? I deleted like 150 rows but it didn't cause the .bak file size reduce. It increased! I didn't shrink database and I don't want to do it.

I'm not sure what to do about it. Is there any other decent way of Logging user accesses?

Comment: This isn't necessarily an exact duplicate, but I recommend taking a look at marc_s' answer to this question: [reducing-size-of-sql-backup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305107/reducing-size-of-sql-backup)

Comment: Deleting rows isnt going to reduce the size of .mdf file so the size of backup file. you will need to execute [`DBCC SHRINKDATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) command to reduce the size of your mdf file. But please read on this before you use this method as it can defragment indexes and a lot more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I typically export the rows from the production server, and import into a database on a non-production server (like my local machine), then delete the existing rows from the production server. Also run an optimize on the production server table so the size is recalculated. This is somewhat manual but it keeps the production server table size down, and the export/import process is rather quick.